# Changing links based on data range. Basic error I can't find, I am trying to echo case 10

Tags: php, date

```
<?php

$next_month = strtotime("+1 month");

//
$next_month_formatted = date("n", $next_month);

$link = "";

if(! empty($next_month_formatted))

    switch($next_month_formatted % 5)
    {
        case '10':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/10-1-15-MCDONALDS-e13aff/token/da0d4ec67cf";
        break;
        case '11':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/11-1-15-MCDONALDS-a0a0ec/token/8232d7c2265";
        break;
        case '12':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/121-15-MCDONALDS--89d5a0/token/84b88a8c248";
        break;
        case '1':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/1-1-16-MCDONALDS--fa49d9/token/79dd025e3f1q";
        break;
        case '2':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/2-1-16-MCDONALDS--022aff/token/4bc0a37cf49";
        break;
        case '3':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/3-1-16-MCDONALDS--d1313d/token/47b351070c1";
        break;
        case '4':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/4-1-16-MCDONALDS--0cf9d2/token/bb31f6bb11e";
        break;
        case '5':
            $link = "https://rightsignature.com/forms/5-1-16-MCDONALDS--37e75d/token/d1b044125f2";
        break;
        default:
            $link = "#";
    }
    echo $next_month_formatted(10);
?>
```

I am trying to get the return value but I have a false function. I'm  little bit new so I can't exactly depict what it is. I am changing the date based on data range.

I'm trying to echo for the current month. I am trying to reflect Octobers link which is case 10.

Comment: `switch($next_month_formatted % 5)` - you're using mod on your month; are you sure that's exactly what you want to be doing?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: ? I don't need a course I need assistance.

Comment: I fixed it there was a lot wrong.

Answer (score 0):

after the switch, you echo this:

```
echo $next_month_formatted(10);
```

shouldn't you echo $link instead?

```
echo $link;
```

Comment: Yes exactly I had all ready fixed it but at the time this would've been helpful. Thank you! :)